# background image from part of png file

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have this image:

[image]

How can I used part of the .png file as an image? I want to use upper part for my `<a class="non_check">` and lower part for my `<a class="checked">` classes as background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use appropriate CSS. You could combine fixed `width` and `height` and `background`, `background-position` properties, like this:

```
.checkbox
{
    width: 23px;
    height: 42px;

    background: url(checkbox-icons.png);
}

.checkbox.unchecked
{
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.checkbox.checked
{
    background-position: 0 -21px;
}
```

Fixed size causes only the desired rectangle of the background to be visible and by changing the `background-position` property, you can define exactly which fragment should it be.

Comment: Here you are. Those are pixel coordinates defining the position of the background image. First number is the X coordinate and second is the Y coordinate. So for `.unchecked` state it's `0 0` (background starts exactly with the element's origin) and for `.checked` state it's `0 -21px` (background is offsetted half of it's height to the top — because your example image is 42px high).

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use CSS image sprites. With image sprites, you can show just the part of the image you want to use.

For example:

```
a.checked {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background:url('image_here.png') 0px -20px;
}

a.unchecked {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background:url('image_here.png') 0px 0px;
}
```

- The `background` property defines the image that will be the background of the div.
- The numbers following the image link  define the position (the first number is the `left` and the second number is the `top`).

### JS Fiddle Example

[CSS Sprites: What They Are, Why They’re Cool, and How To Use Them](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Answer (score 0):

You need a layer (like DIV or SPAN) half the height of an image.
You place the image to the background and by setting background-position, you can move the image parts to the view or out.

Answer (score 0):

You will be using background-position for this with a :hover.  Something like this:

```
.checkbox {
background:#ffffff url('checkbox.png') no-repeat 0 0;}
width:23px
height:21px;
}

.checkbox:hover {
background:#ffffff url('checkbox.png') no-repeat 0 21px;}
width:23px
height:21px;
}
```